# move c++ project to eclipse

Tags: c++, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I have moved a c++ project, which I have previously built using cmake, to eclipse using the steps in this tutorial. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-unix-eclipse/index.html . I am working on mostly the same part of the project, a demo folder. Before eclipse I was using the typical make and then ./demo commands in the terminal. And now I managed to get the project build and run in the IDE with the following build.xml file content :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="unzip" default="make">
    <description>
        Ant adaptor for the demo Makefile.
    </description>

    <target name="make" description="build demo">
        <exec executable="make">
        </exec>
    </target>

    <target name="demoExec" description="run demo">
        <exec executable="./demo">
        </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

But things are running externally now, the two commands are associated with some executables. I switched to Eclipse for primarily debugging reasons but this current configuration do not seem to allow that. How can I get things running natively in Eclipse ,not bound to external tools, so that I can set breakpoints in my code and etc?

Comment: Oh, dear. Just spend 10 minutes to learn gdb and you will set yourself free from this huge and silly IDE that makes you inefficient. Unix is IDE in itself.

Comment: well i already know the basics of gdb, but print vectors and complex classes it is not readable at all, i cannot go on to write my own print functions for the tons of classes i have; not to mention other usability issues because of lack of gui. this is a very nice platform to develop but i won't compare gdb to VS's or even matlab's debugger

Comment: Why did you not stay with CMake? It works perfectly fine with eclipse. I recommend reading: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:Eclipse_UNIX_Tutorial

Comment: @guenis: Did you know you can automate that with gdb? You can have something like automated debugging tests even to verify your program :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to debug a program, no matter how it was compiled (but it does not hurt if debug info is enabled and optimization turned off, as usual).

You just need to create debug configuration and specify the binary file ("c/c++ application") there, probably using "browse" button.

If this does not work for you, what problems are you having?